# Soundcloud API - Is the search working on comments body?

Tags: soundcloud

I was wondering if it's possible to use SoundCloud APIs to search in comments body.

the following request doesn't seems to return correct results:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/comments?client_id=<myclientid>&q=marco
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not an option of the API.